# Arduino - Byte array not updating

Tags: arrays, arduino, byte

I have a byte array declared as:

```
byte b_seconds[8];
```

and I can clear it with this:

```
  void clear_seconds() {
      for (int x = 0; x < 8 ; x++) {
        b_seconds[x] = 0b00000000;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am updating the byte array to send to some shift registers to light 60 LEDs in succession as part of a clock project.

To update the byte array I have this function:

```
void update_seconds(int _secs) {
  if (_secs == 0) {
    clear_seconds();
    bitSet(b_seconds[0], _secs);
  }
  if (_secs > 0 && _secs < 8) {
    bitSet(b_seconds[0], _secs);
  }
  if ((_secs > 7) && (_secs < 16)) {
    bitSet(b_seconds[1], _secs);    
  }
  if (_secs > 15 && _secs < 24) {
    bitSet(b_seconds[2], _secs);
  }
  if (_secs > 23 && _secs < 32) {
    bitSet(b_seconds[3], _secs);
  }
  if (_secs > 31 && _secs < 40) {
    bitSet(b_seconds[4], _secs);
  }
  if (_secs > 39 && _secs < 48) {
    bitSet(b_seconds[5], _secs);
  }
  if (_secs > 47 && _secs < 56) {
    bitSet(b_seconds[6], _secs);
  }
  if (_secs > 55 && _secs < 64) {
    bitSet(b_seconds[7], _secs);
  }
}
```

So I send the seconds to the `update_seconds` function, and all is well for the first array `b_seconds[0]`, but then when the seconds get to 8 and beyond they do not update the appropriate array.

I have checked and can set a `print` function in each of the sections, which prints, but the arrays are not updated as per the `bitSet()` function.
This means at the end of each minute I end up with `b_seconds[0]` correct as 0b11111111 but all the others are 0b00000000 which is not correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you do things like you do, but you can't use `bitSet(x,n)` in a byte when n > 7.

The numbers in `_secs` you use in `bitSet(b_seconds[i], _secs)` can be too large (larger than 7), as you only have 8 bits available to set in each byte in your array.

See [bitSet() documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/bits-and-bytes/bitset/) for more.